# jQuery easing functions without using a plugin

Tags: jquery, easing-functions, jquery-easing

I'm looking for an online list of custom easing functions that I can use with jQuery.

I'm not interested in using a plugin for this, nor am I using jQuery UI.

I found one below that does a nice little bounce but I'm looking for a few others just so I can have some options.

In lieu of of other functions, a brief explanation of how this one operates and might be modified would be awesome.  Thank-you!

Example:

```
$.easing.custom = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158; 
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
}
```

---

EDIT #1:

Here's an online demo of all jQuery UI easing functions.  Source functions from UI are posted below in correct answer by Jake.

http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

---

EDIT #2:

It turns out that the example easing function I posted above is exactly the same as the "easeInOutBack" from jQuery UI.

---

EDIT #3:

Here are some more stand-alone easing equations free for downloading...

http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/

Comment: how about d-ling those plugins and taking just the easing functions from them ?
i doubt youll find a listing of just easing functions...

Comment: Thanks!  Jake posted the source easing functions from UI above... exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I definitely value the updates to your question! Thank you!

Comment: For those interested, jQuery UI has been internally using a very [compact function](http://pastebin.com/raw/sn7JwPtX) that provides the 30 additional easing types. A minified version can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/2WrLApGi).

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Provided that you follow the BSD licensing provisions, you can cherry-pick the easing functions that you want directly from the jQuery UI source code. Note that some of these functions depend on other functions within the list.

To view and compare these easing functions in action, see: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

```
/*
 * jQuery Easing v1.3 - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
 *
 * Uses the built in easing capabilities added In jQuery 1.1
 * to offer multiple easing options
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - jQuery Easing
 *
 * Open source under the BSD License.
 *
 * Copyright 2008 George McGinley Smith
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
 * provided with the distribution.
 *
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 * GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
*/

// t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c: change In value, d: duration
$.easing.jswing = $.easing.swing;

$.extend($.easing,
{
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        //alert($.easing.default);
        return $.easing[$.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
    },
    easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
    },
    easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
    },
    easeInOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
    },
    easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if (t==0) return b;
        if (t==d) return b+c;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
        return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
        return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    },
    easeOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
    },
    easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
    },
    easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c - $.easing.easeOutBounce (x, d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
    },
    easeOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
        } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
        } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
        } else {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
        }
    },
    easeInOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < d/2) return $.easing.easeInBounce (x, t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
        return $.easing.easeOutBounce (x, t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
    }
});

/*
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - EASING EQUATIONS
 *
 * Open source under the BSD License.
 *
 * Copyright 2001 Robert Penner
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification,
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 *
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials
 * provided with the distribution.
 *
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 * GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 */
```

Comment: why the def: 'easeOutQuad' at the top?

Comment: @jedierikb In the jQuery UI library, easeOutQuad is the default easing function.

Comment: But of course! Thanks for pointing out that I could have poked into jQueryUI itself!

Comment: If you're using jQuery in compatibility mode, you can wrap it with (function($) {....})(jQuery); Or you can replace every occurance of $ with jQuery...

Comment: By "borrow" you mean illegally copy by disregarding the licensing terms, right?

Comment: Isn't this just a really small, custom... plugin?

Comment: @Ziggy Yeah, it is. I took OP's question to mean, "easing functions without spinning up a full jQuery plugin in a separate file". Also, I figured that anyone who is really determined to un-pluginify one of these functions can do a simple reformat so that the function can live outside an object: `function easeInQuad(x, t, b, c, d) {return c*(t/=d)*t + b;}`.

Comment: @Jake that's cool, I was just concerned about the HerrSerker's answer below, which got 3 downvotes for reasons that appear to me to be mainly pathos. Bez is really cool, and its only 43 lines of code.

Comment: @Jake The entirety of the easing equations is absolutely a substantial portion. Also, the version you've pasted above isn't even copyright jQuery, it's copyright Robert Penner and released under the terms of the BSD license. It is, in fact, 100% of the content of his work. Please stop ignoring copyrights and licenses and refrain from giving bad legal advice.

Comment: @ScottGonzález Thank you for the additional information. In my haste to gather the source the original answer, (Ctrl+F: "easeoutquad"; Ctrl+C) I didn't notice that this portion was under the terms of the stricter BSD license, and under a different copyright holder. I have updated my response to include the BSD license text.

Answer (score 7):

Usage:

```
$('#clickedDIV').animate({
    marginLeft : '90%'
},800,'easeInOutExpo');
```

**Paste the following in at the bottom of your javascript file, exactly as is.** Then, use as if jQueryUI was installed, as per above.

```
jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];

jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
    def: 'easeOutQuad',
    swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
        return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
    },
    easeInQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuart: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((t-=2)*t*t*t - 2) + b;
    },
    easeInQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*(t/=d)*t*t*t*t + b;
    },
    easeOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t*t + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutQuint: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t*t*t + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * Math.cos(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + c + b;
    },
    easeOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sin(t/d * (Math.PI/2)) + b;
    },
    easeInOutSine: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c/2 * (Math.cos(Math.PI*t/d) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeInExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==0) ? b : c * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t/d - 1)) + b;
    },
    easeOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return (t==d) ? b+c : c * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * t/d) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutExpo: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if (t==0) return b;
        if (t==d) return b+c;
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (t - 1)) + b;
        return c/2 * (-Math.pow(2, -10 * --t) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    },
    easeInOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return -c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - t*t) - 1) + b;
        return c/2 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t-=2)*t) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return -(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
    },
    easeOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d)==1) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*.3;
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*t) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p ) + c + b;
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
    },
    easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
    },
    easeOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
        return c*((t=t/d-1)*t*((s+1)*t + s) + 1) + b;
    },
    easeInOutBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
        if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158; 
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
        return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
    },
    easeInBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c - jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, d-t, 0, c, d) + b;
    },
    easeOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
        } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
        } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
        } else {
            return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
        }
    },
    easeInOutBounce: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if (t < d/2) return jQuery.easing.easeInBounce (x, t*2, 0, c, d) * .5 + b;
        return jQuery.easing.easeOutBounce (x, t*2-d, 0, c, d) * .5 + c*.5 + b;
    }
});
```

---

Source:

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Comment: $('ul#nav').delay(35).slideDown(300,'easeInExpo');

Answer (score 5):

For anyone using a packager like Webpack to bundle server-rendered assets, I encountered a `Error: TypeError: _jquery2.default.extend is not a function` error ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158548/extend-is-not-a-function)).  I was able to get around this by using `Object.assign()` instead of `$.extend`:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'

// Extend jQuery easings with easeOutCubic
$.easing = Object.assign({}, $.easing, {
  easeOutCubic: (x, t, b, c, d) => {

    return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * t + 1) + b

  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the bez plugin for jquery ( http://github.com/rdallasgray/bez ) which lets you create custom bezier easing functions.

If you want to fiddle around with the 4 bezier parameters, here is a online tool, where you can easily get the desired params: http://cubic-bezier.com

Here's the code

```
/*!
 * Bez @VERSION
 * http://github.com/rdallasgray/bez
 * 
 * A plugin to convert CSS3 cubic-bezier co-ordinates to jQuery-compatible easing functions
 * 
 * With thanks to Nikolay Nemshilov for clarification on the cubic-bezier maths
 * See http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2011/05/calculating-cubic-bezier-function.html
 * 
 * Copyright @YEAR Robert Dallas Gray. All rights reserved.
 * Provided under the FreeBSD license: https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez/blob/master/LICENSE.txt
*/
jQuery.extend({ bez: function(coOrdArray) {
        var encodedFuncName = "bez_" + jQuery.makeArray(arguments).join("_").replace(/\./g, "p");
        if (typeof jQuery.easing[encodedFuncName] !== "function") {
                var        polyBez = function(p1, p2) {
                        var A = [null, null], B = [null, null], C = [null, null],
                                bezCoOrd = function(t, ax) {
                                        C[ax] = 3 * p1[ax], B[ax] = 3 * (p2[ax] - p1[ax]) - C[ax], A[ax] = 1 - C[ax] - B[ax];
                                        return t * (C[ax] + t * (B[ax] + t * A[ax]));
                                },
                                xDeriv = function(t) {
                                        return C[0] + t * (2 * B[0] + 3 * A[0] * t);
                                },
                                xForT = function(t) {
                                        var x = t, i = 0, z;
                                        while (++i < 14) {
                                                z = bezCoOrd(x, 0) - t;
                                                if (Math.abs(z) < 1e-3) break;
                                                x -= z / xDeriv(x);
                                        }
                                        return x;
                                };
                                return function(t) {
                                        return bezCoOrd(xForT(t), 1);
                                }
                };
                jQuery.easing[encodedFuncName] = function(x, t, b, c, d) {
                        return c * polyBez([coOrdArray[0], coOrdArray[1]], [coOrdArray[2], coOrdArray[3]])(t/d) + b;
                }
        }
        return encodedFuncName;
}});
```

Comment: As per the title of this question, I am not interested in a plugin.  The online tool at the second link is broken in Safari.  In Firefox, it's only working partially.

Comment: Well, in fact you **are** looking for a plugin, because every easing function is **always** a plugin. And this is a small plugin which easily can create myriads of easing functions just by changing parameters

Comment: Semantic games aside... in fact, I was not interested in a "plugin" and specifically asked for a solution _"without a plugin"_.  I just wanted to choose an easing function and manually copy those two or three lines of code into my page.  Read my original question again along with the helpful edits & links at the end.

Comment: This is not pure semantic game. The plugin is just copying the one line of minified code into your JS File and you are done.

Comment: Three lines of JavaScript **manually** written into my page _by me_ is **not** called a "plugin".  If it were then every single line of JS everywhere is also a "plugin".

Comment: Typically, I think of a jQuery "plugin" as something that begins with `(function($){` and ends with `})(jQuery);`.

Comment: @HerrSerker I was going to downvote this, because the OP didn't want a plugin... but actually the plugin you suggested is shorter (43 lines) than the answer accepted by the OP. I'm amazed that the anti-plugin stigma would extend beyond what is reasonable. If you had posted the entire Bez plugin here as an answer, it would have been shorter and more elegant than the accepted answer, and would probably have been upvoted. Since you linked to a git repo, you got downvotes. Sociology!

Here is an updated link: https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez

Comment: Official definition of a jQuery plugin: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/
_A jQuery plugin is simply a new method that we use to extend jQuery's prototype object._

Comment: @Ziggy, I accepted the answer because it contains a wide variety of easing functions where I can easily extract and copy only the lines of code needed for one easing effect.  I am not "anti-plugin".  I am merely against installing a package with 24 functions where I'll only need to use one.

Comment: @Sparky So you are not anti-plugin, but anti-library? :) Let's just end this semantic war.

Comment: Semantic _war_?  I haven't commented on this thread in years, and when I did, it's pretty clear it's not about semantics:   _"I am merely against installing a package with 24 functions where I'll only need to use one."_