# $.extend is not a function

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs, conflict

I'm trying to integrate the [svg edit - editor](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/), which is using jQuery, into Magento. The problem is that Magento uses Prototype, and therefore I'm using the `jQuery.noConflict();` method. Everything is fine until if I call the editor via function then Firebug throws the following errors:

**$.extend is not a function**

```
if(config) {
   $.extend(curConfig, config);
}
```

**$.isArray is not a function**

```
} else if($.isArray(key)) {
```

The error occurs at line [59](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svgcanvas.js#59) and [121](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svgcanvas.js#121) in [svgcanvas.js](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svgcanvas.js#59). I hope someone with more experience in using jquery and prototype can help me with this problem.

Comment: The problem is (as far as I can see from the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svg-editor.js)), that the editor directly accesses the **global** `$` (instead of aliasing the global `jQuery`). Only calling `jQuery.noConflict();` does not help you here, it seems you have to adjust the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: `jQuery.extend(curConfig, config);`

Comment: Thank you all for quick reply, after replacing all **$.** with **jQuery.** and **$(** with **jQuery(** the errors disappeared. I really did not want to do it this way but it seems to me to be the easiest and fastest way to nearly 4000 lines of code. THX!

Answer (score 5):

try to put your function attr into

```
(function( $ ){


})( jQuery );
```

so it will look like

```
(function( $ ){
jQuery.fn.attr = function(key, value) {
    var len = this.length;
    if(!len) return this;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var elem = this[i];
        // set/get SVG attribute
        if(elem.namespaceURI === svgns) {
            // Setting attribute
            if(value !== undefined) {
                elem.setAttribute(key, value);
            } else if($.isArray(key)) {
                // Getting attributes from array
                var j = key.length, obj = {};

                while(j--) {
                    var aname = key[j];
                    var attr = elem.getAttribute(aname);
                    // This returns a number when appropriate
                    if(attr || attr === "0") {
                        attr = isNaN(attr)?attr:attr-0;
                    }
                    obj[aname] = attr;
                }
                return obj;

            } else if(typeof key === "object") {
                // Setting attributes form object
                for(var v in key) {
                    elem.setAttribute(v, key[v]);
                }
            // Getting attribute
            } else {
                var attr = elem.getAttribute(key);
                if(attr || attr === "0") {
                    attr = isNaN(attr)?attr:attr-0;
                }

                return attr;
            }
        } else {
            return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
    return this;
};


})( jQuery );
```

Comment: $ will be stolen from prototype :( he's facing a classical prototype and jquery conflict

Comment: @Anton S: No... $ will be limited to the anonymous function scope, and it will get passed the jQuery object... What genesis is doing is a very common trick to avoid framework conflicts.

Comment: sorry mates , my mistake, sure it will be anonymus

Answer (score 4):

try

```
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
```

then your call uses **k** instead of **$**.

Answer (score 1):

did you change the jQuery namespace with noConflict. You seem to be still using $ to invoke the func. Change the Jquery namespace using the noConflict approach to something like $$ or maybe jQ then invoke your method like jQ.extend instead of $.extend..