# btn.attr("title") is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, undefined

After I could solve the [namespace problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158548/extend-is-not-a-function) between jQuery and Prototype, with the help of the friendly community here I have another problem to integrate the [Svg Edit(or)](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) into Magento. Now I get a new error message in firebug: `btn.attr("title") is undefined` although the variable has multiple return values and I can't see why this isn't working. The error occurs on line [4137](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svg-editor.js#4137) in the [svg-editor.js](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/source/browse/trunk/editor/svg-editor.js) file. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Line 4137:

```
var new_title = btn.attr('title').split('[')[0] + '[' + keyval + ']';
```

**Edit:**

Thats what i get back. Maybe it's the last value which generates the error?:

```
alert(btn.attr('title'));

// Select Tool [1]
// Pencil Tool [2]
// Line Tool [3]
// Rectangle
// Square
// Ellipse
// Circle
// Path Tool [7]
// Text Tool [6]
// Image Tool [8]
// Zoom Tool [Ctrl+Up/Down]
// undefined
```

After changeing the code to @epascarello 's proposal i get more values back than before.
It seems that there are some menu-items missing:

```
alert(btn.prop('title'));

  // ...
  // undefined
  // undefined
  // Edit Source [U]
  // Wireframe Mode [F]
  // undefined
  // Delete Element [Delete/Backspace]
  // Move to Top [Shift+Up]
  // Move to Bottom [Shift+Down]
  // Undo [Z]
  // Redo [Y]
  // Clone Element [C]
  // Group Elements [G]
  // undefined
```

Comment: Maybe try `$(btn).attr("title")`?

Comment: Does `attr` return `undefined` or is the function itself `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

Keep to attr, but check it's defined. Skip it if it's not:

```
if(opts.sel && !opts.hidekey && btn.attr('title')) {
  var new_title = btn.attr('title').split('[')[0] + '[' + keyval + ']';
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var btn = $("#myButton");
btn.prop("title");
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've tried your code:

`var somevar = btn.prop("title");
var new_title = somevar.split('[')[0] + '[' + keyval + ']';`

and it seems that there are more values than i get by the alert() function above. I'll add this to the post.