# Decorated Field JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeOutCubic'` is coming from the console and I believe it is from a JQuery plugin called Decorated Field.

Inside the zip file, I could not find any documentation or commented code that tells me where this plugin came from. If anyone knows where I can find it to update the code or how I can fix the error I mentioned above, I would really appreciate it.

This is the line in the jquery causing the error, I believe.

```
$(this).animate({opacity:0,top:'+=60px'},{easing:'easeOutCubic',duration:170});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?, also this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748617/jquery-easing-easeoutcubic-emphasizing-on-the-ease

Comment: I just updated it to use 1.10.2 from googleapis.com/ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... I guess if you change this:

```
$(this).animate({opacity:0,top:'+=60px'},{easing:'easeOutCubic',duration:170});
```

to this (the animation will be different):

```
$(this).animate({opacity:0,top:'+=60px'},{easing:'linear',duration:170});
```

It will work. Another guess is that that jQuery plugin needs jQuery UI to work. So, try to include it. http://jqueryui.com/.

Comment: Felipe is right. Easing needs jquery ui to work. Including it should solve your problem.

Comment: I changed that line and I no longer get an error in the console. :) The form still doesn't submit, but that's probably a different problem. Thanks!