# jquery easeOutBounce function missing in-spite of including jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have used 3 some jquery related files namely

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/blog/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="/blog/css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/blog/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Now i am trying to use [Humanmsg](http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/) jquery plugin. It had 2 jquery files **humanmsg.js** and **jquery.js**.
I already have latest version of jquery so I haven't included jquery.js file from plugin. Now i am getting the error in Chrome **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'easeOutBounce'   jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4**
I have checked this function to be present in jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js but still the browser is not reading from this file, in-spite showing error for file **jquery-1.7.1.min.js**.
Though the plugin is working when i replace the orignal **jquery-1.7.1.min.js** with the script file in humanmsg plugin(**jquery.js**) but rest of functionality of site depends on the orignal script file, so can't replace it.
Any idea(to remove the problem)/practices (to follow when including various script files from 3rd party).
PS: **humanmsg.js** use jQuery instead of $ ( if it is of any use).
All the scripts files are downloaded completely by browser.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/var/www/blog/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> <!--ORIGNAL-->
    <link type="text/css" href="/var/www/blog/css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/var/www/blog/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>

    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script-->   <!--Plugin jquery file-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="humanmsg.js"></script>
    <link href="humanmsg.css" media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Humanized Messages - Demo</title>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('a.showmessage').click(function() {
            humanMsg.displayMsg('<strong>Success:</strong> <span class="indent">You clicked \''+jQuery(this).text()+'\'</span>');
            return false;
        })

        jQuery('a.showmessage:last').click(function() {
            humanMsg.displayMsg('"Your <strong>Earth</strong> will be reduced to a burned-out cinder."');
            return false;
        })
    })
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p class="links">
        <a href="#" class="showmessage">Click Me to show message</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

---

I have found [Gritter](http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/), good alternative for humanmsg and its working fine with latest version of jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the plugin, Humanmsg, [is more than 4 years old](http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/downloads/detail?name=Humanized%20Messages%201.0.zip) and you're using jQuery version 1.7.1.

A lot has changed within jQuery since version 1.1.  Looking inside Humanmsg, reveals all kinds of superseded methods.  Using `.bind`, for example, where jQuery 1.7 prefers the new [`.on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

You'll have to find a more up to date plugin as I would not recommend using jQuery 1.1 with today's browsers.

You could try adding the easing plugin, or [just the one easing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin), but you still have the much larger issue of your plugin being way out of date.

Comment: i am afraid u r right. Can u suggest any equivalent of humanmsg?

Comment: @Terminal, I'm really not sure about your requirements or what this plugin was supposed to do.  It's just a small amount of code.  Go through it line by line, updating it to work with today's version of jQuery.  Also see my link above about just using a single easing function without using a plugin... you could easily build the one easing function right into it.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/humanmsg/wiki/UsingHumaneMessages) for your plugin:

> Humane Messages requires the jQuery javascript library. Also
>   recommended, but not required, is the jQuery plugin, [Easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/); to give
>   just the right bounce to the animations.

The easing plugin they use is at http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/ which I don't see that you've included.

Comment: As he already stated, he's using jQuery UI and [it already includes easing](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html) functions.  You can see `easeOutBounce` [within jQuery UI here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js).

Comment: @Sparky672 - However the documentation for that plugin does not mention jQuery UI at all. I realize that jQuery UI has easing incorporated (now), however based on the age of this plugin I doubt it used it for that, and it instead recommended the other easing plugin.

Comment: It does not mention jQuery UI because jQuery UI probably did not exist (was first released in Sept 2007) when it was written... the plugin is a dinosaur and will likely never work no matter what other things he includes.

Comment: I have tried included Easing plugin, the error is gone but message is still not fading out...I think i got to switch to other plugin!!