# How to change jQuery's animation transition from linear to quadratic

Tags: jquery, animation, effects, slide

I think I noticed that all jQuery transitions (e.g. slide effect) work in a linear way. That means that the speed of the animation never changes.

I wondered if it would be possible to change this to a more quadratic behavior. That means, I want the animation to slowly start and then get faster.

Is there a way in jQuery to accomplish this?

Comment: Check out this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's true, most jQuery function have an easing parameter (fadeIn/out, slideDown/up)
If you use [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) (i make an example) you can specify an `easing` option which defaults to `swing`. If you want it `linear` you must specify it

```
.slideDown( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

Taken from the docs

> **Easing**
>   As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may be used. Easing functions specify the speed at which the
>   animation progresses at different points within the animation. The
>   only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default,
>   called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called
>   linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins,
>   most notably the jQuery UI suite.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all jquery transitions have support for easing:

```
$('#something').animate( { left: 96 }, 'fast', 'swing' );
// 'swing' is the name of the easing function
```

A larger set of easing possibilities are available in this plugin: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/