# rewrite this code to flying with easing not fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to rewrite this code, so it would fly in with easing not just fade in.

Code -

```
jQuery('#swiftslider-slide-'+newSlide).addClass('active').fadeIn('300');
```

Could you give me a full example? I understand I must use .animate() but if I do like this -

```
jQuery('#swiftslider-slide-'+newSlide).addClass('active').animate({opacity: "show"}, { duration: "slow", easing: "easein" });;
```

it doesn't work.

Hope you will be able to help me.

Comment: It's not working because, by default, there's no such thing as `easein` in jQuery.  Without using your own function or plugin, [the only two default jQuery animation easing options are `swing` and `linear`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin) to learn more about easing functions.

Comment: okay, but how does the other sliders (premium sliders), get sliding effects, like slide from left to right, from top to bottom e.c?

Comment: They `animate()` the `position` of the element.  See [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Sparky672.

> It's not working because, by default, there's no such thing as easein
>   in jQuery. Without using your own function or plugin, the only two
>   default jQuery animation easing options are swing and linear. See this
>   question to learn more about easing functions.