# Custom jQuery Easing Function With Access to Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I looking up to make a custom easing function to jQuery animate, and I Found a great example to how extend the easing in jQuery. Check it out: [Looking for jQuery easing functions without using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5207301/1233788).

But this approach does not fit my case.
I have a function that need to process the value not only base in time but also base in start and and value. Example:

```
$("selector").animate({ "height": "1400px" }, 1000);
```

the approach that I found uses a function that receives 5 parameters, all of then related with time.

But I need more thatn that. I also need the start value (the value that the DOM has before the animation) and the end value (the value that the DOM will be after the animation).

In my example the value refers to height (original height and 1400px).

I know that you're wondering why I need the value info, so I already wrote my custom function:

```
var offset = 400;

function myEasing(millisecondsSince, totalMilliseconds, startValue, endValue) {
    var t = millisecondsSince / totalMilliseconds;

    if (startValue == 0) startValue = 0.000001;

    if (t <= 0.5) {
        var m = (Math.log(endValue - offset) - Math.log(startValue))
                / (0.5 * Math.LN10);
        var n = Math.log(startValue) / Math.LN10;
        return Math.pow(10, m * t + n); // y = 10 ^ (mx + n)
    }

    var m = 2 * Math.pow(offset, 0.2);
    return Math.pow(m * t - m, 5) + endValue; // y = (mx - m) ^ 5 + endValue
}
```

But my problem is how to incorporate this function to `jQuery.animate()`. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

These are my first keystrokes on SO, I have neither an account or profile nor any reputation,
but I'm working on a jQuery plugin that will allow additional arguments for easing functions.

To answer your question I make following assumptions (if I'm wrong please tell me and I will update my answer):
1. You use jQuery >= 1.8 (they modified their animation routine there).
2. Your $("selector") may contain more than one element.
3. The startValue of the animated property (here: "height") may differ from one element to another.
4. Whenever there's a way to incorporate your function, you won't insist on using a custom easing.

I see two solutions. To explain what I do and why, here's a snippet from jQuery core:

```
// jQuery creates for each animated property of each animated element a Tween object.
// .run() of its prototype is called at each step of the animation.
Tween.prototype = {
    run: function( percent ) {
        // percent = actual state of the animation, a number between 0 (start) and 1 (end)
        // percent is identic with your var t, you dont need to recalculate it
        // this refers to the whole Tween object you are actual in
        var eased,
            hooks = Tween.propHooks[ this.prop ];

        if ( this.options.duration ) {
            // here the choosen easing function is called. It must be declared in $.easing under its name
            // before animation is running, otherwise an error is thrown. But before starting you don't know
            // the startValue, so your function can't reference to it
            this.pos = eased = jQuery.easing[ this.easing ](
                // here the  five arguments are passed in. Every easing function in $.easing, even custom ones,
                // have this signature (x, t, b, c, d), they may use the arguments or not. Changing this signature
                // breaks any other code that relies on easings
            percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration
                // But being shameless, you may extend the signature with the additional arguments you need
        /*  percent, this.options.duration * percent, 0, 1, this.options.duration, this.start, this.end  */
                // now there are seven arguments and you can restructure your function to use the three you need
            );
        } else {
            this.pos = eased = percent;
        } // at this point the easing result is stored in this.pos. When using 'linear' its identic with percent
          // (and with your var t) so we can use this.pos in the second solution

        // after calculation this.now holds the actual value of the animated property. When you havn't done
        // the modification above, you can't use your function for easing and this.now hasn't the value you want
        this.now = ( this.end - this.start ) * eased + this.start;

        if ( this.options.step ) {
            // if you have defined a function in options.step it gets called now. Two arguments are passed in:
            // the actual value, the whole Tween object. The latter holds all values you need
            // to recalculate this.now with your function
            this.options.step.call( this.elem, this.now, this );
        }

        if ( hooks && hooks.set ) {
            hooks.set( this );
        } else {
            Tween.propHooks._default.set( this );
        }
        return this;
    }
};
```

Solution 1: You have done the modification of jQuery described above. Then:

```
var offset = 400;
$.easing["myFunction"] = function(x, t, b, c, d, startValue, endValue) {
    /* replace your var t with x; args t b c d not needed; your done; */
};
$("selector").animate({ "height": "1400px" }, 1000, "myFunction");
```

Solution 2: You won't mess around inside jQuery. Then:

Instead of discrete arguments for duration, easing and complete you can pass an options object to .animate().
For details see http://api.jquery.com/animate/ .
With specialEasing you can define the easing of each property separately. This way you keep all possibilities
to animate other properties than "height" in the same call without affecting them with "myFunction".

```
$("selector").animate(
    { height: "1400px" , otherProp: "otherVal"}, {
        duration: 1000, // your duration
        specialEasing: {
            height: "linear" // easing happens before step, linear won't confuse your calculations
            otherProp: "anyEasingYouWant"
        },
        step: function(now, tween) {
            // you are restricted to the two arguments jQuery passes to this function. But the Tween object
            // holds all values you need to modify tween.now (= the animation output value) as you like
            // if you animate more than one property and want apply your calcs only to one, do exclusions here.
            // it's needed cause this function is executed once for each property of each element at each step.
            if (tween.prop !== "height") return;
            var ofs = 400, // your offset
                stv = tween.start || 0.000001, // your startValue
                env = tween.end, // your endValue
                dif = env - stv, // difference between start and end to recalculate the actual value
                pos = tween.pos, // your var t
                m, n;
            if (pos <= 0.5) {
                m = (Math.log(env - ofs) - Math.log(stv)) / (0.5 * Math.LN10);
                n = Math.log(stv) / Math.LN10;
                tween.now = dif * Math.pow(10, m * pos + n) + stv; // y = 10 ^ (mx + n)
            } else {
                m = 2 * Math.pow(offset, 0.2);
                tween.now = dif * (Math.pow(m * pos - m, 5) + env) + stv; // y = (mx - m) ^ 5 + endValue
            }
        }
    }
);
```