# fullpage.js jQuery UI elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullpage.js

I'd like to strip down jquery UI to the bare minimum required for fullpage.Js. Can you please tell me exactly which parts of jQuery UI are necessary for operation? All of this is in jQuery UI: 
* Includes: jquery.ui.core.js, jquery.ui.widget.js, jquery.ui.mouse.js, jquery.ui.position.js, jquery.ui.accordion.js, jquery.ui.autocomplete.js, jquery.ui.button.js, jquery.ui.datepicker.js, jquery.ui.dialog.js, jquery.ui.draggable.js, jquery.ui.droppable.js, jquery.ui.effect.js, jquery.ui.effect-blind.js, jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js, jquery.ui.effect-clip.js, jquery.ui.effect-drop.js, jquery.ui.effect-explode.js, jquery.ui.effect-fade.js, jquery.ui.effect-fold.js, jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js, jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js, jquery.ui.effect-scale.js, jquery.ui.effect-shake.js, jquery.ui.effect-slide.js, jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js, jquery.ui.menu.js, jquery.ui.progressbar.js, jquery.ui.resizable.js, jquery.ui.selectable.js, jquery.ui.slider.js, jquery.ui.sortable.js, jquery.ui.spinner.js, jquery.ui.tabs.js, jquery.ui.tooltip.js

That's a lot, and I'd like to reduce the size.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include jQuery UI at all. After a casual glance at the code (and documentation), it appears the default easing function (easeInQuart) is the only thing using jQuery UI.

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#usage

Set the easing option to `linear` or `swing` to use jQuery's default easing.

Comment: Also, you could take only the easing functions you want to use from jQuery as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin).

Answer (score 2):

Well, what a question. If you want to minimize to only what you use, I suggest you roll-your-own file at: http://jqueryui.com/download/

You can choose specifically which pieces of the jQuery UI you want to include in your file and get it in regular and minimized versions.

Where fullpage.js does not specify what they use or not, you may have a bit of trial and error to see what you can drop out. I would guess they use quite a few of the animations.

Comment: Also an option, but not quite exactly what I was looking for. It's an option, though. +1.