# How to set a 'easeOutBounce' for .scrollTop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set a  `easeOutBounce` for a webpage `back-to-top` button .

I have below code for `.scrollTop` but unable to add

```
{
    duration: 2000,
    easing: "easeOutBounce"
}
```

Existing .js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Show or hide the sticky footer button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
});

// Animate the scroll to top
$('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show or hide the sticky footer button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
  });

  // Animate the scroll to top
  $('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900, 'easeOutElastic');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap{height:2000px;}
  .in1, .in2{height:250px;margin-top:50px;}
  .in1 {border:1px solid blue;}
  .in2 {border:1px solid red;}
button{margin-top:50px;font-size:3rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="in1"> Scroll down</div>
  <div class="in1">Down a bit more</div>
  <button class="back-to-top">Back To Top</button>
</div>
```

Or, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show or hide the sticky footer button
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 500) {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $('.back-to-top').fadeOut(200);
    }
  });

  // Animate the scroll to top
  $('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('html, body').animate(
      {scrollTop: 0},
      {
        easing: 'easeOutElastic',
        duration: 1500
      }
    );
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap{height:2000px;}
  .in1, .in2{height:250px;margin-top:50px;}
  .in1 {border:1px solid blue;}
  .in2 {border:1px solid red;}
button{margin-top:50px;font-size:3rem;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="in1"> Scroll down</div>
  <div class="in1">Down a bit more</div>
  <button class="back-to-top">Back To Top</button>
</div>
```

---

Useful sites:

http://easings.net/  (usage examples at bottom)

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/quick-tip-add-easing-to-your-animations

[Install just the easings to get around requirement for jQueryUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin)

Comment: It is bouncing with a 'easeOutElastic'  instead of  'easeOutBounce'. I need download link of jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js and jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: I found this code in https://jqueryui.com  .  Can I use this code remain unchanged?

Comment: **(1)** I changed the easing to Elastic only for demo purposes (because `easeOutBounce` was not as visible when I was writing the solution). **(2)** Note that jQueryUI is required for both of those easings, BUT you can also [install the easings by themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin) and then you don't need to install jQUI. *Just going ahead and installing jQUI was easiest for me when writing the answer.*