# How to create the equivalence of CSS "ease" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, easing

According to [Ceaser](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/), the detailed CSS code of CSS transition-timing-function `ease` is `cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000)`. That's all I know. How can it be translated it into a jQuery's easing function?

jQuery's `$.easing` allows us to define custom easing functions. For example, the following code defines a custom easing function called "custom". (Note: The code is borrowed from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin).)

```
$.easing.custom = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    var s = 1.70158; 
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*(t*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t - s)) + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*(((s*=(1.525))+1)*t + s) + 2) + b;
}
```

And then it can be used like this: `$('#element').animate({ right: 100 }, 500, 'custom')`.

What I want to do is defining a custom easing function called "ease" with code like this:

```
$.easing.ease = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `JqueryUI`: https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Comment: @SohaibMohammed Not sure if I missed something, but I checked its API documentation and didn't found the equivalence of CSS “ease”.

Comment: Well! there are too may jquery libraries can make this! google theme.

Comment: I usually use GreenSock in animation and easing: http://greensock.com/ease-visualizer

Comment: _"What I want to do is defining a custom easing function called "ease" with code like this:"_ What have you tried? What issue are you having?

Comment: @guest271314 I had tried searching for a converting tool which converts cubic-bezier into jQuery equivalence, and had no luck. My issue is that I don't know how to write the custom jQuery easing function.

Comment: What `javascript` have you tried to resolve Question?

Comment: @guest271314 None because my current javascript skill level is not high enough to write such mathematical functions.

Comment: See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transitions/#funcdef-transition-timing-function-cubic-bezier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no online converting tool or tutorial for converting cuic-bezier into jQuery equivalence.

But I found a jQuery plugin which can serve the purpose, too. The plugin is [Bez](https://github.com/rdallasgray/bez).

So in my case, the CSS transition-timing-function `ease` can be translated into jQuery with Bez as: `$.bez([0.250, 0.100, 0.250, 1.000])`.

Comment: Aray ko bez. Good answer!